# No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit

I got a problem when I use retrofit to send parameter. Please help me to solve this.

This is the interface :

```
@POST(Config.URL_PAYMENT)
fun sendPayment(@Body id:String, total: Long): Call<List<ProgressAntar>>
```

This the rest

```
private fun sendPayment(id: String, total: Long){
    Log.i("getDataProgress", "dataProgress$id")

    val apiService : Service = Client.getClient()!!.create(Service::class.java)
    apiService.sendPayment(id,total).enqueue(object : Callback<List<ProgressAntar>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ProgressAntar>>?, response: Response<List<ProgressAntar>>?) {
            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.i("tesSucess", "sucess" + response.body())
                val list = response.body()

                if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Tidak ada daftar pembayaran", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else{
                    // refresh progress list
                    progressList = ArrayList(list)
                    dataProgressAdapter.updateData(progressList)
                }
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Tidak ada daftar pembayaran", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `total: Long` is not annotated, so Retrofit doesn't know how to forward it to your API.

You might need `@Field` instead of `Body`.

Comment: for me it was the 5th parameter had no Annotation.
So make sure you use `@Body`, `@Path` ...etc for the parameter being passed to the function in Service interface